# Debugging Windows 8 App for surface pro tablet

Tags: debugging, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-debugging

I have released an app for windows 8, desktop users are happy with it but surface tablet users are complaining crash issues as soon as app starts.

Now i dont have surface tablet to debug the app although i have tried on inbuilt simulator and it works perfectly on simulator too.

So how can i debug my app on windows surface tablet, is there any settings that changes simulator environment  to target surface pro tablet.

Comment: You mention Surface and Surface Pro, which would be two completely different architectures (ARM versus x86/x64) - do you have a link to the app?

Comment: @JimO'Neil, http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/veen-rss-reader/f8598f12-d0bd-4fb0-8a5f-dbf7e4a00885

Comment: @JimO'Neil, few users have complained app crashes as soon as it starts. And I am still unable to find a way to debug issues that those users might be facing. What do you recommend.

Comment: I ran on Surface RT and didn't spot an issue, so can't be too much help here. It crashes before they even see the Google login via Web Auth Broker?  I noticed it didn't ask me to login on RT when I'd already logged in via another installation on the desktop (roaming settings?) -  not sure if that's a scenario where there could be an issue?

Comment: In the US, the Microsoft evangelists have devices and schedule office hours (see ohours.org) to provide assistance like this. I don't know if our colleagues in India do the same, but you could [reach out to them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/events/bb905078.aspx) and see what resources may be available local to test/debug on an actual device.

Comment: Also try this link to get local help https://applabs.msregistration.com/

Comment: @JimO'Neil, thanks. Issue is resolved(i have found the bug). Actually 2 guys reported crash issue and both were on surface tablet. So i thought there might be some issue with this app on surface tablet.

Comment: @JimO'Neil: it didn't asked for login on another device yes because of roaming settings.

Comment: @JimO'Neil: one user reported that app crashes even before he see the google login via Web-Auth-Broker (he shared his screen to me i myself saw that, but user didn't co-operated much so his issue is not yet resolved), any guess why app crashed??

Comment: Try running in the Local machine. Metro apps are built to run both on Win 8 PC and Tablets.. You might find the problem there :)

And for a better experience you can install the app package through powershell in ur WIn 8 machine and try check for the issues. Might Help but not sure ...